# Python: Filtering multiple conditions for ALL columns

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a df here:

[image]

and I'm trying to do some filtering based on certain conditions. It works just fine when I've done this all based on one condition but I can't do the same thing as pythonically as I'd like because all search results I see work based on one specific column. That and the type of searches also include strings. What I'm trying to do is filter to find the count of how many rows have a value that's higher than a 3 AND also lower than a 7 (These are all integers so they'd have to have a 4, 5 and 6.)

Sure, with a row count of 5, I could just count but this is just a subset of a much larger data frame.

I've also already tried this resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-conditions/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer I got was:

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: (x < 7) & (3 < x), axis=1)]
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].count()
```

All the values are the same count, but that's fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: (3 < x) & (x < 7)).apply(all, axis=1)]
```

Comment: I tried this but it resulted in zero options, which I know isn't true because there are at least a couple.

Comment: Are you sure your columns are in `numerical` dtype? You can convert them to so with `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The dtypes are all int64.

Comment: So I was able to remove all values that didn't fit the conditions and turn them into N/As, but now I have the values instead of the count of the non-N/As.

Comment: OK I'll post the answer I got in the OP. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `&` to compare two boolean df's

```
(df.gt(3) & df.lt(7)).any(axis=1)
```

you can also use `isin()` with `range`

```
l = 3
h = 7
df.isin(range(l+1,h)).any(axis=1)
```